# .NET control that inherits Combobox - Items.Clear does not clear the list of items

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox

I have a class that inherits ComboBox.

I have a property that receives a List(of String) and sets the Items collection to the same values. Except, when I clear the Items list it does not always clear!

```
Set(ByVal value As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String))
    MyBase.Items.Clear()
    If MyBase.Items.Count <> 0 Then
        'Shouldn't ever get here
        Throw New Exception
    End If

    For Each item As String In value
        If item Is Nothing Then
            Items.Add(String.Empty)
        Else
            Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
End Set
```

Anybody have any ideas as to what could be going on?

EDIT:

I changed my code to provide a look at what's in the variables:

```
Set(ByVal value As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String))
    Debug.WriteLine("values passed to property: " & Join(value.ToArray, ", "))
    Dim itemvalues As String = String.Empty
    For Each item As String In Items
        itemvalues &= item & ", "
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("items in combobox: " & itemvalues)
    Items.Clear()
    If Items.Count <> 0 Then
        'Shouldn't ever get here
        Throw New Exception
    End If

    For Each item As String In value
        If item Is Nothing Then
            Items.Add(String.Empty)
        Else
            Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
End Set
```

And this is what I get:

```
values passed to property: a, c, b
items in combobox: 
values passed to property: a, c, b
items in combobox: a, c, b, 
values passed to property: a, c, b
items in combobox: 
values passed to property: a, c, b
items in combobox: a, c, b, 
values passed to property: a, c, b
items in combobox: a, c, b, 
values passed to property: a, c, b
items in combobox: a, c, b, 
values passed to property: a, c, b
items in combobox: a, c, b, 
values passed to property: a, c, b
items in combobox: a, c, b,
```

Failed to clear after the last pair of debug.writeline

Comment: can you associate some other action that happens before with when it doesnt work?  e.g. fails when the user does xxxx or yyyy

Comment: What do you mean by "not always"?

Comment: By not always, I mean that sometimes it clears the list and other times it does not. What else would I mean? ;-)

Comment: @Plutonix - I haven't been able to identify anything different about the iterations through this piece of code that are different for when it clears vs. when it does not.

Comment: By changing Throw New Exception to Exit Property, I get the behavior I want. But it still bothers me that a built-in control method is misbehaving. I was attempting to update this list when the control lost focus (to implement history for the control)... if I removed the LostFocus handler which sets this property and instead directly called the method which updates this property it works. Not sure why.

Comment: Your problem isn't with the code you posted. You are likely getting confused by referencing several controls and clearing the wrong one or something. If this line `Throw New Exception` is not getting hit, you dont have an items after the CLEAR method.  Try putting `me.handle` in your writeline() to make sure this is the same control everytime.

Comment: @Steve: The control is clearing itself. There is only 1 control. And the line Throw New Exception IS getting hit. That is the point! It shouldn't ever be executed.